# Running CMD command from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some Python code that I would like to run from Excel VBA, the python code interacts with the Excel document. If I run it from a CMD window in the folder that holds the code it look like this:

```
python code.py
```

It runs, however if I run it from VBA with the command

```
cmd = "python" & """" & pth & "\code.py" & """"
Shell cmd, vbHide
```

Nothing happens, and no error is shown. I have tried several solutions but nothing seems to work, the weird part is that on other computers it works so I'm assuming there are no issues with the code. Is there a reliable way to run from within VBA a cmd command? What Am I missing?

Comment: Your two commands aren't the same.

Comment: The calls aren't the same, and you've not shown how you attempt to execute `cmd` in your VBA code, so it would be impossible to tell you why it isn't working. Assigning text to the string `cmd` doesn't run anything - it just assigns text to the string.

Comment: Updated to make it more clear and show the way I'm trying to run it from VBA

Comment: Use full paths.